# How can i create multiple subfolder inside the zip file using ICSharpCode.SharpZipLib.Zip ---- please ignore .. this issue has been resolved

Tags: c#

I am downloading the files from the Azure blob container. My code is working fine if I create only one directory but if I tried to create multiple directories the zip file getting corrupted.

```
   var users = new List<long>();
                   users .Add(1);
                   users .Add(2);
                   users .Add(3);    
   foreach (var user in users)
   using (var zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(Response.OutputStream))
               {
   
                   foreach (CloudBlockBlob item in container.ListBlobs(prefix: blobNamePrefix, useFlatBlobListing: true))
                   {
                       zipOutputStream.SetLevel(0);
                       var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(item.Name);
                       var entry = new ZipEntry(item.Name);
                       zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(entry);
                       blob.DownloadToStream(zipOutputStream);
                   }
                   zipOutputStream.Finish();
                   zipOutputStream.Close();
               }
       
               Response.BufferOutput = false;
               Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "zipFileName.zip");
               Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
               Response.Flush();
               Response.End();
   }
```

if I only use one user then its create a new folder inside the zip file and add all the user blob file inside that. but did worked for multiple.

Comment: For resolved questions, either you give/accept an answer, or simply delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that the using zipOutputStream is inside the for each block for users.

It will work for one user but not for several.

Move the the for each block for users inside the using zipOutputStream block.